# Vinogradov inequality for composite number?

Tags: number-theory

Vinogradov inequality for a prime $p$ is given by $$\big|\sum_{a=N+1}^{N+M}(\frac{a}{p})\big|\leq \sqrt{p
}\times log(p)$$ (in terms of Legendre symbol), where $N, M$ are arbitrary $(0\leq N < N+M < p)$.
There is a generalization of the result in which the prime $p$ is replace by composite $k$. Can anyone suggest me any book or research paper, where this inequality in composite form is given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Legendre symbol is generalized to the composite case by the Jacobi symbol.

The Pólya-Vinogradov inequality still works fine for these, because the original proof applies to arbitrary Dirichlet characters. So for $q$ composite, you stil have:

$$\bigg|\sum_{a=N+1}^{N+M}\bigg(\frac{a}{q}\bigg)\bigg|\leq \sqrt{q} \ \log q$$

Most textbooks on analytic number theory are good a reference for it, and a source of references for proofs and improvements. See for example Iwaniec & Kowalski, "Analytic Number Theory", chapter 12, "Character sums".